# Linux home server hung last week - how to determine cause?

Tags: centos

I have a lightly used home server (that is, I store back-ups on it, it syncs to CrashPlan, and it runs some media sharing services I use locally - it's not too active).

Today I discovered that it was in a hung state (couldn't SSH into it, router did not see it) so I pressed the physical power button to shutdown and started it again.

I wanted to check the logs to see if there was anything that could tell me what happened, but so far all I can see is the approximate time that it stopped responding (just saw a gap in messages in /var/log/messages up to the point where I just rebooted). Is there anything else I can check after the fact to see why this happened? Or did I need to force some kind of dump before I powered down? I'm just curious to make sure this won't happen again. I suppose if it does happen I should hook up a monitor and keyboard to see if there is any information.

System is running CentOS 6.5